# Pronouncing kanji of day of the week

Tags: pronunciation, readings

Something I find very useful about Japanese is that events are often posted with the date along with the day of the week (something I see rarely when in the United States). For example:

> REOL 第一弾【だいいちだん】作品『Σ』リリース決定【けってい】!!
>
> 2016.10.19（水）発売【はつばい】

From that I understand that the album will be released on 19th October, a Wednesday. I would like to know how to read the **（水）** part in my head and out loud (as if I were reading the page to somebody).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Days of the week are often abbreviated in speech such that they're cut off before the 曜日, so you can refer to days as げつ・か・すい etc. In the case of writing, you can read it however you like, really, since it's just an abbreviation. If you want to just think すい then go ahead, but you can read it internally as 水曜日 if you so wish. If you were to see something like "Mon." or "Th" in English as an abbreviation of a day, how would you read it in your head? The point is it doesn't really matter how you read it as its primary purpose is just as an indicator of the day and not a piece of prose. If I were reading it aloud to someone, I'd say the full 水曜日.

Answer (score 0):

I think no one accuses you of reading "(水）​発売" out as "Sui hatsubai,"  but it's safer for you to read it out "suiyoubi hatsubai" to avoid a phonetic confusion, such as with "新発売 - shin hatsubai" - newly on sale.

In the same token, you don't read out 2016.10.19 (土) as "nisenju-uroku-ju-u kyu-u do,"　which sounds like 2016.19℃.